# Animate.css not working properly

Tags: html, css, animate.css

So, I've tried to use `animate.css` and I have finally got it to work. But some of the animations cause the element I'm using it on to move from it's original position, but not everything.

Does anybody know what causes it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>deadinside</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
  </head>

  <script src="js/ctrl.js"> </script>

  <body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeypress="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" onkeydown="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" >

    <video autoplay="true" loop="true">
      <source src="videos/antarctica.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="videos/di.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>

    <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/deadinsiide" target="_blank"><img src="img/deadinsiderw.png" width="484" height="87" class="image animated fadeInUp"/></a>

    <script src="js/f12.js"> </script>

  </body>
</html
```

.

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding:  0;
}

video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

}

.text {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

a {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 6em;
    color: white;
    text-align:
}

.image{
    position: fixed;
    /*element can move on the screen (only screen, not page)*/

    left:50%;top:50%;
    /*set the top left corner of the element on the center of the screen*/

    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*reposition element center with screen center*/

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

   z-index:10000;
   /*actually, this number is the count of the elements of page  plus 1 :)*/
   /*if you need that holds the element top of the others. */
}
```

Comment: sample code please?

Comment: I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. The way I centered the image was the problem.